# Terminal Velocity Equation

Tags: classical-mechanics

A ball of unit mass is dropped. How do I work out it's terminal velocity when the ball has air resistance proportional to the square of the velocity?

Comment: You have not to solve any differential equation: see [derivation for terminal velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_velocity).

Answer (score 0):

Let the position of the ball be $y(t)$. According to Newton's second law $$y''= -k y'^2 $$

Plugging in $y'=p(y)$ the equation becomes $$pp'=-kp^2 $$
which can be solved for $p(y)$ by separation of variables.

Can you take it from here?